# How do I hide irelevant game logic?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, shortcut

Unfortunately, I'm a pretty sloppy organizer when it comes to blender. This leaves me with a bunch of "spaghetti" logic all over the place. Is there a way to hide the logic that I'm not using? I tried plain ol' <kbd>H</kbd> and that didn't do it.

[image: Spaghetti]

Comment: Yeah... that would be great. um... If I knew how.

Comment: An answer that said how would be cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another easy thing you can do to temporarily simplify your logic editor is unchecking the **Link** check box

This logic mess may seem a bit overwhelming
[image]

Simply un-checking the **Link** box can Significantly simplify your workspace, at least long enough to figure out what you were trying to do.

[image]
 When you have wires connecting bricks across multiple objects, and especially when you have scroll bars and hundreds of wires between your bricks, you can sometimes forget what you were trying to do before you find the right sensor or actuator.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can make your logic setup more workable.

One of the simplest is to use messages to trigger events between multiple objects.

[image: Cube a and Cube b]

## Cube A                                                                   Cube B

Logic setup for **Cube A**
[image: Cube A's logic]
Logic setup or **Cube B**
[image]
This could be the same thing as this logic setup, only when you are dealing with many more objects, and with more logic bricks, it gets *Very* confusing, *Very* fast.
[image]
Based on this, we can conclude that when anything collides with **cube A**, a message will be sent to **Cube B** (`ThisCouldBeAnything`) When **Cube B** receives this message, it will play the animation of itself spinning around 360°

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two more methods you might find useful when trying to organize your logic.  They are *Very* basic but are usually sub-consciously ignored. Many blender users (myself included) are guilty of this.

## Name the logic

## Arrange the logic ***sensibly***.

Compare this
[image]

To this

[image]

It technically does the same thing, but it Much harder to decipher in case you ever needed to edit something.

Comment: But I don't *want* to be logical....