# How to keep logic bricks organized?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

When I make something in logic bricks, I try to have everything always neat. I always end up with a lot of bricks that lead to a brick way upwards and/or way downwards. When I make edits, I would usually erase everything and start again. I would like to organize this in any way. Is there a way you can put a little divider to just store a certain function? This way, when I start a new function, everything would be leveled. Is there a plugin for this if this does not exist? I know you can do this in programming in just about every language. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I have been given a question that, in some ways, can be seen as a duplicate. I am **not** looking to have my logic bricks behind the scene, by unselecting the link button. I am looking to have layers of logic organized by what can be a divider; this feature is most likely not in the engine, so I am probably looking at an addon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide irelevant game logic?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26608/how-do-i-hide-irelevant-game-logic)

Comment: @X-27 His question seems quite different. I am looking for some sort of a divider, not what he wanted and found.

Comment: Then no, as of now there is no possible way to do this. However It should be closed as a feature request, Not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request.

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate. @BlenderDev did you read the answers given? they could help you.

Comment: They did not help, and I edited the question. 1 hour later it tells me to edit it again, I don't need to look at it again, I need whoever marked it again to look at it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Organizing with states

You can use the states of the build-in state machine to group your bricks.

This allows to quickly show/hide/switch logical groups. You can do that by selecting/deselecting states in the visible-state-bar.

### Requirements

Make sure all states with logic are enabled in the initial-state-bar.

### Example

This way you can group this logic:
[image]

into movement logic:
[image]

using logic by keyboard

[image]

and using logic by mouse

[image]

Hints

- You do not need to use the state machine operations (state
  switching).
- You can select multiple states at the same time by
  holding  when selecting/deselecting a state.
- If you need more than the 30 available states I think it is time to review your design. Most-likely this object simply does too much. It would be better to spread the logic over multiple objects.